# Determine $\forall a\in\mathbb{R},$ the number of solutions to the system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

So the system is

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcr}
x-y+az & = & 1 \quad \quad(1)\\
2x-y + z & = & -1 \quad \quad (2)\\
ax+y-z & = &1 \quad \quad(3)
\end{array}\right.$$

Going matrix $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\2&-1&1\\a&1&-1&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Row reducing by Gauss elimination. I now assume $a\neq0,$ and

1. multiply $(1)$ by $2$ and compute $(2)-2(1).$
2. multiply $(1)$ by $a\neq0$ and compute $(3)-a(1).$

This gives

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\&1&(1-2a)\\&(1+a)&-(1+a^2)&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\1-a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Finally, I take $\text{row}(3)-(1+a)\cdot\text{row}(2):$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\&1&(1-2a)\\& &-(1+a^2)-(1-2a)(1+a)&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\(1-a)+3(1+a)\end{bmatrix},$$

which simplifies to

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\&1&(1-2a)\\& &(a+2)(a-1)&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\ 2(a+2)\end{bmatrix}.$$

This implies that $$z=\frac{(a+2)(a-1)}{2(a+2)}=\frac{2}{a-1}.$$

By this we can see that

- for $a=1\Rightarrow z=0$ we have no solutions.
- for $a=-2$, there are no solutions.
- for $a\in \mathbb{R} / \{1,-2\}$, there exists only one solution.

But how do I deal with my original assumption of $a\neq0?$ What should I say about it? Clearly for $a=0$ there exists a solution, but I had to assume it was not equal to zero in order to multiply with it.

Comment: None of the steps you made requires $a\ne0$. Think to it:when you do $R_3-aR_1$ and $a=0$ you are simply doing nothing. Anyway, for $a=-2$ the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: But in order to multiply or divide by an unknown value, it has to be other than $0.$ It doesn't say in the problem statement that $a\neq 0.$

Comment: @Parseval Your formula for $z$ is not correct see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I know I edited it.

Comment: @Parseval It should be $z=\frac{2}{a-1}$.

Comment: Ah, yes ofcourse! Thanks.

Comment: @Parseval Why? Dividing by $0$ is of course disallowed, but multiplying by $0$ is well-defined. Not always good for the job, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your matrix row reduction (which is correct)
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&a\\0&1&(1-2a)\\0&0 &(a+2)(a-1)&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\ z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-3\\ 2(a+2)\end{bmatrix}$$
we obtain that

- for $a=1$ there are NO solutions (because from the last line $0=6$).
- for $a=-2$, there are INFINITE solutions: 
  $$(x,y,z)=(-2-3z,-3-5z,z)\quad \mbox{for $z\in\mathbb{R}$.}$$
- for $a\in \mathbb{R} / \{1,-2\}$, there exists only one solution:
  $$(x,y,z)=\left(0,\frac{a+1}{a-1},\frac{2}{a-1}\right).$$

There is no need to consider the assumption $a\not=0$.

Comment: But if $a=-2$, doesnt the fraction for the $z$-value become undefined?

Comment: @Parseval  No. If $a=-2$ the equation $(a+2)(a-1)z=2(a+2)$ becomes $0=0$ which holds for any $z$.

Comment: If the last equation becomes 0=0, does it always hold that the system has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @Parseval. Yes (if the rest of the system is consistent) In this case $z$ is free and $x=−2−3z$ $y=−3−5z$.

Comment: So in general, if the last line, after elimination is $k=k$, then the system has a unique solution. If the last equation is $0=k$ (for some $k\neq 0$), there exist no solutions and if the last line reads $0=0$, there are infinitely many solutions that one can be express in parameter form by substituting for example $z=t$ and solving for the other variables in terms of $t$?

Comment: @Parseval More simply any equation $k=k$ can be eliminated from the system. Then solve the reduced system.

Answer (score 1):

Let me call the rows $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ for better clarity.

The row transformations you perform are

1. $R_2-2R_1$
2. $R_3-aR_1$
3. $R_3-(a+1)R_2$

None of these requires special assumptions; for example, the second one, in the case $a=0$ would be “do nothing” and you need nothing special for it, do you? Also the third transformation is OK and needs no assumption.

The row transformations that require special attention are those of the form “multiply row $k$ by $\lambda$” where the coefficient $\lambda$ *must* be different from zero.

When I teach the subject, I introduce row transformations with symbolic names:

1. $E_i(c)$ for “multiply row $i$ by $c$
2. $E_{ij}(d)$ for “sum, to row $i$, row $j$ multiplied by $d$”
3. $E_{ij}$ for “swap rows $i$ and $j$

The limitations are

1. for $E_i(c)$ we need $c\ne0$
2. for $E_{ij}(d)$ we need $i\ne j$
3. for $E_{ij}$ we need $i\ne j$

This is because we want the row transformations to be *reversible*. You go back to the previous state by doing, respectively,

1. $E_i(c^{-1})$
2. $E_{ij}(-d)$
3. $E_{ij}$

and you clearly see that $d=0$ makes no problem at all.

Note that you got mixed up at the end. For $a=-2$, the last equation becomes $0=6$ (hence no solution); for $a=1$, the last equation is $0=0$ and, due to the form of the matrix, the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: But here I DID "multiply Row1 by a". Does it always apply that when the last equation takes the form of 0=0, there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @Parseval No! You did “sum $R_1$, multiplied by $a$, to $R_2$”.

Comment: Ok, but what I'm trying to say is that, no matter what row, is till multiplied a to something. So, a multiplication with a variable of unknown sign has taken place.

Comment: @Parseval That's irrelevant; as I said, if $a=0$ you'd have done nothing, which is a perfectly good transformation, isn't it?